# how to retrieve files when there is a problem with how the HDD treats the computer?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

i have a problem with my SEAGATE EXPANSION PACK 500GB EXTERNAL HARD DISK DRIVE(HDD). At first, it wasnt recognizable by the PC. Then we discovered that the pin was stuck so we fixed it and now it can connect and is recognized by my computer. Although, another problem came up. The disk drive was recognized but it does not know what kind/type of HDD it is. It did not know its capacity/size. it seems to be a hollow/blank drive. My expert friend said there was a problem with how the HDD treated the computer.

please help me mankind, i really need to retrieve those files...:( please

Comment: More applicable to superuser.com

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Reliable, but dangerous method is

1. acquire (for while) equal hard drive
2. replace your HDD PCB with one from equal HDD
3. copy information to another storage (aside of two HDDs mentioned above)
4. replace PCBs back
5. give the equal HDD back to its owner

But, it may be disconnection inside the enclosure, so one should disassemble the enclosure and check, if the drive itself securely connected to converter.